# Issue with creating a timer using setInterval(): updates way too quickly

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

(Firstly, let me say that the code for this is in my github repo: [Click Here](https://github.com/amosallaei19/NEURepo))

The repo should give you all the clues necessary to what the issue is, however if you were to open up the `index.html` file and click, a counter should start in the top left corner. It seems to work perfectly for a bit, however if you click a lot and drag the mouse and move it around the page for a bit, the counter suddenly goes insane and counting rapidly.

I can't find where the issue is with the code doing this; I gave `setInterval()` a specific time to update `timer`, however after moving the mouse, a bunch of clicks, and dragging the mouse, etc...the counter goes crazy. Normally it wouldn't be too bad of an issue, however the site I am implementing this on requires a lot of clicks and mouse movement.

My next issue is that I cannot find a way to stop counting on `mouseup`. At the moment, when mouse is down OR up, the counter count. However, I want it to start counting when left-click is held, and stop when I take my finger off left click. I've tried a `while` loop like `while (mouseDown === true) ...` and that just doesn't load the page correctly.

Any help is appreciated!

```js
let mouseDown = false;
let delta;
let isDragging = false;
var mY = 0;
//var currSpeed = $(document).cursometer('getCurrentSpeed');
let hello;
let timer = 0;
let pastTime;
let speed;

function collTime() {
    timer += 1
    $("#class").text(timer)
    mouseDown = false;
    }


$( document )
    .mousedown(function() {
    isDragging = false;
    mouseDown = true;   
    var cancel = setInterval(collTime, 1000)
 
})
    
    .mouseup(function() {
    isDragging = false;
    mouseDown = false;
    timer = timer
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
<body>

<div id="class">

</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

To reproduce issue: Left Click, left click and drag mouse, and just do random mouse events inside the run box very wildly. You will notice the issue.

Comment: Please reread [ask]. Code should be within the question, as a [mcve], not as an external link.

Comment: Please provide a small snippet of code, and give more specific repo steps that re-create your problem. It would help to also give a more broad overview of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Alright, my apologies. I will edit the question

Comment: @LGSon I have added the code snippet. The issue still should exist

Comment: @katamaster818 added steps to reproduce issue

Comment: Everytime you click, you add a new timer without clearing out the previous. If you click 10 times, you're now running 10 `collTime` concurrently, because you've called `setInterval` 10 times.

Comment: Read up on [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)

Comment: @TylerRoper So how am I supposed to fix this? Should I put my `cancel` variable in a `for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)` so it only does it once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `setInterval()` with every click, but you never clear out the previous one. If I click 10 times, that's now 10 concurrent intervals.

If you `declare` cancel at the root with the rest of your variables, you can access it from within your click event. This allows you to clear it out before you reset it.

```
let cancel;
```

```
clearInterval(cancel);
cancel = setInterval(collTime, 1000)
```

```js
let cancel;                               //Cancel is now global
let mouseDown = false;
let delta;
let isDragging = false;
var mY = 0;
let hello;
let timer = 0;
let pastTime;
let speed;

function collTime() {
  timer += 1
  $("#class").text(timer)
  mouseDown = false;
}


$(document)
  .mousedown(function() {
    isDragging = false;
    mouseDown = true;
    clearInterval(cancel);                //Remove the previous timer
    cancel = setInterval(collTime, 1000)  //Create a new one
  })
  .mouseup(function() {
    isDragging = false;
    mouseDown = false;
    timer = timer
  });
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="class">

  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Huh. This seems to solve both of my problems. Thanks a bunch, and I apologize for the wording and including of my code!

Comment: No worries, including code makes it much, much easier to solve.